# Responsive CSS: viewport and 100% doesnt fit so much

Tags: html, css, responsive

I putted this tag in my code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

And then, after a media query I asked

```
header {
    width: 100% !important;
}
main {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

But I have a serious difference when I go to the site in my iPhone.

Safari zoom in the text (main) and the header is much bigger in width.

If I take off the meta tag its too small.

Comment: What is your media query you're "asking"? Is it a typo where your `header` and `main` selectors are meant to be classes (you need to use `.` before them: `.header`/`.main` if they are? Are you sure you're limiting the `body` to the full width of the viewport, or is it being set to bigger, somehow? The `header` and `main` elements will be `100%` of their respective parents. Please include a bit more code so we might be able to see the issue you're having, it's a bit unclear at the moment.

Comment: Also, there's no *huge* need to override style rules with `!important` if you're loading your CSS in the correct order. It's run top-first, bottom-last with the bottom-most styles overriding any above them (unless `!important` is used somewhere above).

Comment: Well sorry if i'm not so clear, i'm french. 
Actually, i did like the website: alsacreations suggested: i putted the css code for mobile devices first and then i putted the regular code in the media query: "@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)". Also, in the beginning of my code I have putted a width of 100% for the body...

Comment: I just putted the important to see f it changed something, i wont let it

Comment: See @wscourge's suggestion below, also - that might help clear a few things up, hopefully :)

Comment: Can i putted the link here with no "dangers" ? Sorry I'm new, and in the older forums I used people always criticze the job before answer the question. I dont pretend I'm the best and i know its always possible to do better. I accept constrcutive advices, but i dont like when people treat people that have lowest knowledges bad... I hope i can trust more in this community than seems more gratefull and thanks for this!

Comment: It's sometimes usually advised against for posting links to problems where the site is likely to change (and affect the question). Usually, if you can post enough code, that will do the trick, and screenshots of unexpected layouts can be very useful. At the moment, there's not a great deal of code to give us an idea of any underlying problem - hence the questions. SO is a great community to be part of - there are some trolls, as I'm sure some will agree. Welcome to the community! :)

Comment: Have a read of this to get you started on asking a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know where is the problem from and what could i giive more to solve it. 
When i take of the viewport, the site is displaying normally but its all very small. I just dont know why with it give different size for different elements that are all 100%.

Comment: I'm not too sure where the problem's coming from, I'm afraid. I would advise having a read up on responsive CSS - there's loads of article and tutorials out there on the web that should be able to give you a better understanding, and hopefully help you to solve your issue :) happy coding!

Comment: I tried to respect "religiously" the tips i read already. I'll try to send you the link in private then if you dont mind... Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way of sending private messages on SO, sorry.

Comment: I see that, I must wait to have the domain then because i have the admin paste that is "open" for now. I might be able to put it in the day... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use **semicolon** to separate content attribute's values, where you should use **comma** instead, like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Do u use any css reset file I can take a look on?

Comment: Yes, i use this one:

Comment: But i have an older version

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, it was something stupid and silly, but I found the reason.

The problem was in the footer in reality: i tried to put the header, the main and the footer in display none to see...

I don't know why i didnt think before...

Sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
    width: 100vw !important;
}
main {
    width: 100vw !important;
 }
```

It's just simple example, if it works for you, recode it, and get rid of important

Comment: But it doesnt work sorry. I stille have the main that is 100% and the header that is 200%...

Comment: FYI: `vw` is "viewport width", likewise you can use `vh` for "viewport height" - the value is in "%" - so, for example `50vw` would be "50% of the viewport width"